# Sublime text 3, Package Controll - cant install packages

Tags: ssl, github, sublimetext3, package-control

I realized like a week ago that I cannot install any new packages via Package Control. I tried everything even reinstalling sublime, while cleaning all files /Library/Application Support/ everything. Still the same problem. Any ideas?

```
ignored packages updated to: ["Emmet", "Vintage"]
reloading settings Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
Package Control: Error downloading package. HTTP exception InvalidCertificateException (Host codeload.github.com returned an invalid certificate ([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:548))) downloading https://codeload.github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/zip/master.
error: Package Control

Unable to download Emmet. Please view the console for more details.
ignored packages updated to: ["Vintage"]
reloading settings Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @RustyFieldstone No, actually to this day the problem persists Switched to Atom

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change the precedence of the downloader in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings`.

```
"downloader_precedence":
{
    "linux":
    [
        "urllib",
        "curl",
        "wget"
    ],
    "osx":
    [
        "curl",
        "urllib"
    ],
    "windows":
    [
        "wininet"
    ]
},
```

Changing `urllib` to `curl` has worked for me.

Comment: `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` must also be set manually if your use `curl`.

Answer (score 3):

**For OSX:**

bhanu's answer is correct but my "Package Control Settings - User" file was not at that exact location. More general instructions:

- Open **Command Palette** (Cmd+Shift+P on Mac)
- Type `Package Control Settings`
- Open 'Package Control Settings - **Default**' and search for `downloader_precedence`
- It probably looks like this - note the default osx downloader is `"urllib"`:

```
"downloader_precedence": {
        "windows": ["wininet"],
        "osx": ["urllib"],
        "linux": ["urllib", "curl", "wget"]
    },
```

- You can't actually edit the Default. Override this setting by going to Command Palette > 'Package Control Settings - **User**'
- Copy-paste the snippet above into the User file (correct indentation and add comma after existing settings if needed) and make `"curl"` the first osx downloader:

```
"downloader_precedence": {
        "windows": ["wininet"],
        "osx": ["curl", "urllib"],
        "linux": ["urllib", "curl", "wget"]
    },
```